# xhr.send and php session value - correct syntax?

Tags: javascript, php, session, xmlhttprequest

What is correct syntax for sending php session data please with xhr.send, my javascript is knowledge is limited I have set the value like this:

```
var csrf_token_value = '<?php echo $_SESSION['csrf_token']; ?>';
```

This sets the csrf_token_vale correctly

Not sure correct syntax for xhr.send, the following does not output the session value it just outputs 'csrf_token_value'

```
xhr.send("csrf_token=" + csrf_token_value);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your request method. If you are using GET, then you'd have to place the token as a query string param in the `open()` function:

```
xhr.open("GET", "/myendpoint?csrf_token=" + csrf_token_value);
```

... before you send it.

If you are using POST then you will need a FormData Object:

```
data = new FormData;
data.set("csrf_token", csrf_token_value);
```

And then send that with your request:

```
xhr.send(form);
```